# To Find Average population Countrywise and rounding off to its nearest value in GRID DB

Tags: griddb

I  am working on a business request. I have two tables Country and State. In the Country table there are 3 columns(CountryID,CountryName, TotalArea. In the State Table there are 4 columns(StateID,StateName,CountryID,Population). I want to write a query
a)  to find the CountryID, Countryname and the average population each country will have
b) Round the average population to the nearest value
c)  display the data in the descending order of the average population.

Please assist me in writing this query in GRID DB

CountryID   CountryName Area
1           India         500789 Sq m
2           USA       1005804 SQ m
3           Pakistan      700854 Sq m
4           United Kingdom 900876 Sqm

StateID StateName   CountryID   Population
1001    Maharashtra 1            258798000
1002    Delhi           1            57646678
1003    Newyork         2            678655
1004    Connecticut 2            876555

Tried using FLOOR and Avg function